# How can I refresh listview from IntentService?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

My app receiving a data from a PHP script. These data form a JSONArray which are taken to populate listview. When I opened Activity with listview I would like refresh a listview after receiving data. How can I to do from IntentService? I have this class in my Activity but when I invoke their from IntentService my app is closed.

```
public void update(){
    ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
    JSONArray JsonArray = config.getJSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray.length(); i++) {

        try {
            JSONObject Json = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            ListData ld = new ListData();
            ld.setStrefa(Json.getString("strefa"));
            ld.setAdres(Json.getString("adres"));
            ld.setKryteria(Json.getString("kryteria"));
            ld.setTelefon(Json.getString("telefon"));
            ld.setData(Json.getString("data"));
            myList.add(ld);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: do this to refresh your list...if (mListAdapter == null) {   
         mListAdapter = new RowAdapter(myList);   
         listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);   
        } else {   
         mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
        }

Comment: It's not work. Before opening an activity is creating a JSONArray from a data received from PHP. Then is creating a listview. Then in background a data are changed and now should be refresh.